# How to change Artist Name tag from uppercase to capitalized in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music, id3-tag

I have set the iTunes media folder location to an external hard drive (with around 10,000 ALAC files, all perfectly tagged, with most common tags), with the consolidating files option by iTunes turned off.

I have Artist Name tags written in uppercase but since I’ll be listening to music more often on mobile devices the uppercase names take more length on the screen and therefore I wish to change them to capitalized (manual custom correction).

When I do that outside of iTunes with the 3rd party tag editor (Tag.app) and open iTunes it still shows the artist name in uppercase.

I tried then to change that tag in iTunes itself in the info. tab (despite the fact that even there it showed the name capitalized), but then it split the album in two with the first song in the 1st and the rest in the 2nd album (which is the same album).

How can I change the artist name tag from uppercase to capitalized (without screwing the iTunes up) and should I do it only from the 3rd party app. or iTunes or both?

Comment: I’m on Mountain Lion 10.8.3. iTunes 11.0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by renaming the (Artist) info. of that one song that iTunes didn’t group with the rest of the songs/album to something else (just added a random letter at the end) and then renaming it back to the original name.

Weirdly, iTunes then recognized the 2 albums as one and grouped the songs together.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use Doug Adams' free [Proper English Title Capitalization](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=titlecaps) AppleScript.

Comment: The script does exactly what I wanted. It changes text to capitalized according to the rules of title capitalization in the English language, it does it from iTunes and affects the files directly.

_However_, the problem persists. iTunes _splits_ the album in two, as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like iBatch would do what you want.

It's $5. And there's a free trial.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibatch-for-itunes/id444082460?mt=12

Comment: Totally worth the $5. Also, it fixes many "split albums" for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could also run a script like this in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with t in selection
        tell t
            set artist to my titlecase(artist)
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell

on titlecase(x)
    do shell script "ruby -rubygems -KUe 'require \"titlecase\"
    print ARGV[0].downcase.titlecase' -- " & quoted form of x
end titlecase
```

The titlecase gem can be installed with `sudo gem install titlecase`.